Complicated JSON body for POST request to REST API
I am working with an older application in C# on .NET 4.0.
I am using HttpClient to call an API with an authentication with a bearer token, and that all seems straight forward. Where I am struggling is creating the "Content" that I need to add to the httpClient.PostAsync method.
I can fairly easily output exactly what I need to a string, but I can't figure out how to use any serializer to create the JSON the API is expecting.
Here is the body that I can send successfully in Postman:
mutation createAccounts {
    schema {
    insertJobs(input: {
        Name:   "John Doe 10/09/2024",
        ExternalID: "52660"
        Contacts: {
        FirstName: "Sam & Sarah",
        LastName:  "Doe",
        MobilePhone: "555-333-4444",
        DefaultContact: true,
        ExternalID: "98765"
        
        }
    })
    }
}

How can I build this into proper content to submit?
I have been looking for examples, but all I have found have a simple output from a single class.

That isn’t json..

It looks like the request you're sending through Postman is a GraphQL request. Are you certain that the API to which you're sending data is expecting it in JSON? There is a  GraphQL package for .NET can add with:
dotnet add package GraphQL

here is the documentation for their tool:
https://graphql-dotnet.github.io

You are correct.  It does use graphql.  Unfortunately when I tried to get the graphql tool, it requires .net 4.6... this application is on .net 4.0
